# my button id when call in javascript works but onserverclick event not works that store and update data on sql

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, function

this is button coding here id use in javascript and onserverclick to trigger event in C# to add or update data

```
<button id="update" type="button" runat="server" class="button" 
onserverclick="Unnamed_ServerClick">Update</button>
```

this is javascript code to show popup modal when user change password and it shows error in this window with validation

```
<script> 
var update = document.getElementById('update');
update.onclick = function () {
childmodal.style.display = "block";
</scrip>
```

when i remove id then onserverclick works but popup window disappears not show any validation acknowledgement if id use with it to hold modal then onserverclick not works thanks in advance plz any solution my final year project part and i have no day left to waste on it plz help

Answer (score 0):

I think you have multiple tag with same id="update"